# gitlab & gitolite: права, пользователи и т.п

Tags: git, gitlab

Привет! Переезжаю с gitolite на gitlab 9.0.5 и встал вопрос: Возможно ли как-то, хотя бы примерно, разграничивать права юзеров как в конфигах gitolite? В последнем я делал это автоматически скриптами, а в gitlab знаю только как через вебу это делать, собсно возможно ли как-то это автоматизировать? Например: создать нового юзера и автоматом дать ему права девелопера в определённые проекты и группы.

Comment: У вас Community или Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Ну как, получилось что-нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

Через GitLab API можно получать некоторые данные о пользователях, а с токеном администратора — получать более подробные данные, менять эти данные, заводить новых и удалять существующих пользователей:

- [Создание пользователей](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#user-creation)
- [Редактирование пользователей](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#user-modification)